# Get HTML content from div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find out "Div" tag content from my variable like "No More Events to Show" how could I do that.

Here is my HTML content that has stored in variable.

```
var data="<div class="row events noevents text-center">
         No More Events to Show
     </div>"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried googling before asking the question? there are like a billion links that answer your question!

Comment: And your code is also invalid.....

Comment: tried to find the duplicate of it but failed although there are many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data="<div class='row events noevents text-center'>No More Events to Show</div>"


console.log($(data).html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

1. Wrap in `$()`

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the string into elements, and select elements from it. Try this:

```js
var data="<div class='row events noevents text-center'>No More Events to Show</div>"
var elements = $(data);
var str = $(elements).text();
alert(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to fix the quotes and multiple line string definition. and then create a DOM element and then fetch `.html()` or `.text()`

```js
var data = '<div class="row events noevents text-center"> No More Events to Show  </div>'
console.log($(data).html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```